# Passing content of an array to another array java

Tags: java, arrays, class

I have to create a method that takes the content of an array and adds it to another array.
So my I have a method addTune(Tune t) that adds tunes to a an array.
I have an array of object Tunes (Class Library).

Constructor for Library

```
Library (int size)
{
    array = new Tune[size];
    count
}

public void addTune(tune b)
{
    //check if program can add new tune

    if(count < array.length)
    {
        array[count] = b;
        count++;

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("The Library is full!");
    }

}
```

I also tried to create the addLibrary function but I can't make it work.
addLibrary(Library l) takes a Library parameter.
This is what I wrote

```
public void addLibrary (Library l)
{
    for (int i=0; i< l.array.length;i++)
    {
        array.addTune(l.array[i]); 
    }
}
```

This is supposed to add objects of one array to the other, so if I have a Library object lib with 2 tunes and another Library object lib2 of bigger size, lib2.addLibrary(lib1) should have add the books from lib1 to lib2.
Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `addLibrary` is within your Library class and is meant to add a whole Library to the existing array, you probably meant:

```
public void addLibrary (Library l) {
    for (int i=0; i< l.array.length; i++) {
        addTune(l.array[i]); //just call the addTune method
    }
}
```

`array.addTune(...)` can't work because an array does not have an `addTune` method.

Or even better:

```
public void addLibrary (Library l) {
    for (Tune t : l.array) {
        addTune(t); //just call the addTune method
    }
}
```